# How to align controls in Excel Addin

Tags: c#, excel, alignment, positioning, ribbon

I'm currently working on an Excel addin project in c#, and I'm trying to simply align some controls to the left of the ribbon.
My problem is that the last control just overflows to the right, creating a new column, messing with my pretended UI.
The controls I would like to align vertically are a group with a login label and the input, another group with the key and the input, a login button and at last the cancel button, that is the control that goes to a new column.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Clarifiying: I'm trying to get all the controls on the same column, the first one. Not necessarilly left aligned, but on the leftmost / first column.